# Notation for tautology, inconsistency and contingency

Tags: propositional-calculus

A tautology can be indicated like so: $\models \phi$

What is the notation for an inconsistency? $\not \models \phi$?

What is the notation for a contingency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inconsistency is not $\not \vDash \phi$, because that is merely saying that $\phi$ is not a tautology, so it could still be either an inconsistency or a contingeny.

Instead, an inconsistency is: $\phi \vDash \bot$

When $\not \vDash \phi$ *and* $\not \vDash \neg \phi$, then $\phi$ is a contingency. I personally have not seen one symbol for this.